# how do i adjust the if condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

If want my code to restrict value for xx update to be between 0 and 12 (x_max) but the result is sometimes coming more than 12. can anyone assist? The aim is to minimize a function where the variable is between zero and twelve. When running the code below, the feasible region get violated, that is x becomes larger than 12.

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return -(1.4 - 3 * x) * math.sin(18 * x)

n_par = 20
max_iter = 10
w = 0.5 
c1 = 1  
c2 = 2  
x_min = 0
x_max = 12

xx = []
xxb = []
v=[]
for i in range(n_par):
    xx.append(x_min + (x_max - x_min) * random.random())
    v.append(random.random())
xxb = xx
yy=xx

F = []
for i in range(n_par):
    F.append(func(xx[i]))

ind = np.argsort(F)
xxg=xx[ind[0]]

dom=[]
ran=[]
for i in range(max_iter):
    dom.append(1)
    ran.append(1)

for itr in range(max_iter):
    for i in enumerate(list(range(n_par))):
        v[i[0]]=w*v[i[0]]+c1*random.random()*(xxg-xx[i[0]])+c2*random.random()*(xxb[i[0]]-xx[i[0]])
        yy[i[0]]=xx[i[0]]+v[i[0]]
        if yy[i[0]] > x_min and yy[i[0]] < x_max:
            xx[i[0]]=yy[i[0]]
    
    for ii in enumerate(list(range(n_par))):
        F[ii[0]]=func(xx[ii[0]]) 
        ind = np.argsort(F)
        if func(xx[ind[0]]) < func(xxg):
            xxg=xx[ind[0]]
        for iii in enumerate(list(range(n_par))):
            if func(xx[iii[0]]) < func(xxb[iii[0]]):
                xxb[iii[0]]=xx[iii[0]]
    dom[itr]=itr    
    ran[itr]=func(xxg)

print(xxg)
print(func(xxg))
```

minimize a function but the values are jumping out of the feasible region

Comment: With all the variable names it is hard to tell, however I see no variable `x` so I assume "that is x becomes larger than 12" is some other definition of `x`? One thing I notice is that you have statement like `yy=xx` are you expecting `yy` to be a copy of `xx` or just a different name for `xx`?

Comment: Are you asking about this line: `if yy[i[0]] > x_min and yy[i[0]] < x_max:`? That should implement the check you want.

Comment: `for i in enumerate(list(range(n_par)))` What's the point of this? `i[0]` and `i[1]` will be exactly the same (and you never use `i[1]`). Just do `for i in range(n_par):`

Comment: xx will be replaced by yy iff yy is in between 0 and 12 that is the if condition, and xxg is one of these xx. Final result sometimes gives xxg >12, that is the problem i am having

Comment: @JonSG there is no x variable, sorry i was referring to xx.  it is in between x_min=0 and x_max=12 after some yy is computed yy will replace xx if it is in between 0 and 12 (the if condition). xxg is one of the xx's and it is going beyond 12. That is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set `yy = xx`. Every time you change `yy`, you also change `xx`. Do `yy = xx.copy()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Vegan Chili, it is working now.